# top 5 customers with total dues

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to get top 5 values from a list of data but there's a catch. Let's say the list has name of customers and amounts due from them. But customers' names are repeating. So, I need top 5 customers from this list. So, first we'll have to add and then use large formula to get top 5. But is there a formula we can get this done with in a single formula? I'm currently pivoting it and then using large function to get this done.

Unique Customers Case:

[image]

Repeating Customers Case (the problem):

[image]

*Click on images above for larger view*

Link to file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J2on7BHYTfbMFp0mRbTElCA2vT7tw3QQ

Comment: What is the implication of the repeating names.  Can one customer hold multiple positions, or only one?  Also, in your example, the output is labelled as wrong with no explanation of what right should look like.

Comment: @fixer1234 hi, i've just updated my file. let me know what you think. Yes, one customer can hold multiple positions.

Answer (score 1):

A pivot table is a good way to do this, but you don't need a large formula afterwards. Just get the pivot table to do the sort for you to get the top 5.

In the drop down at the top of the pivot table select 'More sort options', then sort by the sum of the amount owing.

[image]

Comment: hi, I have multiple files with large data set and I don't want to update each and every pivot all the time (that will be really time consuming). I have created a chart of top 5 as well which will get updated once the numbers in the data sets are changed. If I use pivot, i'll have to manually refresh data and also my files will become heavy. Is there a formula or combination of formula which can handle this task?

Comment: @ramsingh check,, I've posted the Solution by using the attached Google Dataset with OP.

Answer (score 0):

***I've suggested this Solution on the basis of the Dataset linked with OP. 
Check the Screen Shot.***

[image]

**NB:**

The Data Range I've used is, A282:C296, so you adjust as you need.

I've sorted the Customer Names along with their Top 5.

The Formula I've use is in Cell I282, finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** finally drag it down.

```
{=MAX((B282:B296=G282)*C282:C296)}
```

Cell G282 is Customer Name A in OUTPUT.

**Note,** your Name list has DUPLICATE, but I've used the FIVE Names picked by you to get their TOP AMOUNT. *Like Name A has 2 values & TOP VALUE is 5,35,454.* **That's why Mine List (in RED Colour) has few different Values.**

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: hi, that is not what I want. I've updated the attachment so that you'll know what I want. I need the solution is the same format but without the help of pivot. Let me know if this is possible.

Comment: @ramsingh, it's not PIVOT TABLE based Solution. I've used the same Data structure what has been attached by you in the Google Sheet.

Comment: You can create the same out of Pivot Table on Excel Sheet and apply the Formula what I've Suggested. Remember, I've TESTED it's working.

Comment: will your formula pick the name automatically??

Comment: Which Name?? If you are talking the Customer List, it can be created by different Formula to get Unique Customer Name List.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following ranking of the data using just formulae:

[image]

**Preprocessing**

The data in columns A and B are raw data, no formulae.

In D4 - [get unique names](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($D$3:D3,$A$4:$A$22)=0),$A$4:$A$22)
```

Make sure the two instances of $A$4:$A$22 get replaced with large enough arrays to cover all your data, and more if your data set will grow.

Drag down far enough that there would be more than enough rows to list each unique name.

In E4 - sumif the amounts owing by each person:

```
=SUMIFS($B$4:$B$22,$A$4:$A$22,D4)
```

Again, make sure the two arrays are large enough to cover all your data, and more if your data set will grow.

Drag down next to column D.

In F4 - [rank without skipping values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065159/truly-unique-ranking-while-ignoring-empty-cells):

```
=IF(E4="","",RANK(E4,$E$4:$E$19)+COUNTIF($E$4:E4,E4)-1)
```

Make sure the range $E$4:$E$19 refers to the whole of the adjacent column data range, and drag down next to column E.

**Results**

In H4:H8 raw numbers typed in, no formulae.

In I4 - index-match to look up names in rank order:

```
=INDEX($D$4:$D$19,MATCH(H4,$F$4:$F$19,0))
```

In J4 - index-match to look up corresponding amounts:

```
=INDEX($E$4:$E$19,MATCH(H4,$F$4:$F$19,0))
```

These two dragged down next to the 1-5 listed in column H.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the support. Is there any way we can do this in a single formula. So, we'll have only 5 rows and the formula will pick the top 5 customers automatically according to the total amount due and the column next to it will get the amount due with the sumif formula. Is this even possible without VBA?